# Extract SVG values and divide them by 1000

Tags: ruby, svg

I have SVG values in an XML file like `209499.728041`:

```
 <path id="dwg-object-136" d="M 209499.728041,19994.245007 209499.728041,27254.245007" style="fill:none;stroke:blue;strok    e-width:4px" />
 <path id="dwg-object-137" d="M 220719.728041,27254.245007 220719.728041,18564.245007" style="fill:none;stroke:blue;strok    e-width:4px" />
 <path id="dwg-object-138" d="M 220719.728041,19994.245007 209499.728041,19994.245007" style="fill:none;stroke:blue;strok    e-width:4px" />
 <path id="dwg-object-209" d="M 214304.728041,35614.245007 A 2000.000000,2000.000000 0 0 0 212304.728041,37614.245007" fi    ll="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="0.100000" />
 <path id="dwg-object-210" d="M 230819.728041,37614.245007 A 2000.000000,2000.000000 0 0 0 228819.728041,35614.245007" fi    ll="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="0.100000" />
 <path id="dwg-object-211" d="M 216007.728041,39574.245007 216007.728041,35614.245007" style="fill:none;stroke:blue;strok    e-width:4px" />
```

Is there a way to divide all these values by 1000 so that it would be `209.499728041`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to cause your SVG content to display within the file at 1/100 scale, the easiest way to do this is wrap them in a common transform:

```xml
<g transform="scale(0.01)">
  <!-- all your paths here -->
</g>
```

But, if you really want to modify the path data, you can do so using the SVG DOM:

```js
// Untested code
function scalePath( path, scaleFactor ){
  var scalable = ['x','y','x1','y1','x2','y2','r1','r2'];
  for (var i=0,segs=path.pathSegList,len=segs.numberOfItems;i<len;++i){
    var seg = segs.getItem(i);
    for (var j=scalable.length;j--;){
      var prop = scalable[j];
      if (prop in seg) seg[prop] *= scaleFactor;
    }
  }
}
```

Note that this (desirably) will not touch the `angle`, `largeArcFlag`, or `sweepFlag` properties of an arc-to command.

You could make the above code slightly more performant by switching on the `pathSegTypeAsLetter` property of the segment and scaling the correct properties per segment type, but I'm too lazy to do so, and computers are fast.

If you are doing this in order to save bytes in the serialization, you probably want to round the values:

```js
if (prop in seg) seg[prop] = Math.round(seg[prop]*scaleFactor);
```

Comment: Thanks , the first solutions works perfectly. However, it doesn't work with 1/1000 scale. like transform="scale(0.001)"